# process video stream from memory buffer

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I need to parse a video stream (mpeg ts) from proprietary network protocol (which I already know how to do) and then I would like to use OpenCV to process the video stream into frames.  I know how to use cv::VideoCapture from a file or from a standard URL, but I would like to setup OpenCV to read from a buffer(s) in memory where I can store the video stream data until it is needed.  Is there a way to setup a call back method (or any other interfrace) so that I can still use the cv::VideoCapture object?  Is there a better way to accomplish processing the video with out writing it out to a file and then re-reading it.  I would also entertain using FFMPEG directly if that is a better choice.  I think I can convert AVFrames to Mat if needed.

Comment: How do you read and decode the buffer? I once integrated OpenCV with proprietary stream by initializing an IplImage object, allocating memory and copying the frame from stream to IplImage using memcpy. In my case I was luck to have a proper raw image from stream.

Comment: @lfagundes the video stream a normal mpeg ts stream once I have extracted it from the proprietary encapsulation.  After that I want to use existing tools (OpenCV preferably) to decode the transport stream and video frames.

Comment: Here is an example of how-to capture a video stream with OpenCV, encode to a buffer as mpeg-4 and then deocde from the buffer: http://dimitri-christodoulou.blogspot.com/2012/02/encode-and-decode-video-from-memory.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had a similar need recently.  I was looking for a way in OpenCV to play a video that was already in memory, but without ever having to write the video file to disk.  I found out that the FFMPEG interface already supports this through `av_open_input_stream`.  There is just a little more prep work required compared to the `av_open_input_file` call used in OpenCV to open a file.

Between the following two websites I was able to piece together a working solution using the ffmpeg calls.  Please refer to the information on these websites for more details:

http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1170

http://cdry.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/using-custom-io-callbacks-with-ffmpeg/

To get it working in OpenCV, I ended up adding a new function to the `CvCapture_FFMPEG` class:

```
virtual bool openBuffer( unsigned char* pBuffer, unsigned int bufLen );
```

I provided access to it through a new API call in the highgui DLL, similar to `cvCreateFileCapture`.  The new `openBuffer` function is basically the same as the `open( const char* _filename )` function with the following difference:

```
err = av_open_input_file(&ic, _filename, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

is replaced by:

```
ic = avformat_alloc_context();
ic->pb = avio_alloc_context(pBuffer, bufLen, 0, pBuffer, read_buffer, NULL, NULL);

if(!ic->pb) {
    // handle error
}

// Need to probe buffer for input format unless you already know it
AVProbeData probe_data;
probe_data.buf_size = (bufLen < 4096) ? bufLen : 4096;
probe_data.filename = "stream";
probe_data.buf = (unsigned char *) malloc(probe_data.buf_size);
memcpy(probe_data.buf, pBuffer, probe_data.buf_size);

AVInputFormat *pAVInputFormat = av_probe_input_format(&probe_data, 1);

if(!pAVInputFormat)
    pAVInputFormat = av_probe_input_format(&probe_data, 0);

// cleanup
free(probe_data.buf);
probe_data.buf = NULL;

if(!pAVInputFormat) {
    // handle error
}

pAVInputFormat->flags |= AVFMT_NOFILE;

err = av_open_input_stream(&ic , ic->pb, "stream", pAVInputFormat, NULL);
```

Also, make sure to call `av_close_input_stream` in the `CvCapture_FFMPEG::close()` function instead of `av_close_input_file` in this situation.

Now the `read_buffer` callback function that is passed in to `avio_alloc_context` I defined as:

```
static int read_buffer(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size)
{
    // This function must fill the buffer with data and return number of bytes copied.
    // opaque is the pointer to private_data in the call to avio_alloc_context (4th param)
    
    memcpy(buf, opaque, buf_size);
    return buf_size;
}
```

This solution assumes the entire video is contained in a memory buffer and would probably have to be tweaked to work with streaming data.

So that's it! Btw, I'm using OpenCV version 2.1 so YMMV.

Comment: I had solved this but forgot to post my solution.  This is indeed how I did it.

Comment: a couple notes: `memcpy(probe_data.buf, data, 4096)` should use probe_data.buf_size not 4096 (or it will crash for inputs smaller than 4096). `av_alloc_put_byte` has been renamed to `avio_alloc_context`

Answer (score 1):

Code to do similar to the above, for opencv 4.2.0 is on:
https://github.com/jcdutton/opencv
Branch:  4.2.0-jcd1

Load the entire file into RAM pointed to by buffer, of size buffer_size.
Sample code:

```
VideoCapture d_reader1;
d_reader1.open_buffer(buffer, buffer_size);
d_reader1.read(input1);
```

The above code reads the first frame of video.

Comment: Would be fantastic, if someone goes through the trouble to add a useful feature, they would also create the pull request to have it upstream. Now the feature rots on the old version instead of being maintained upstream.