# how do i Play mpeg2 ts buffer by buffer?

Tags: visual-c++, buffer, mpeg2-ts

i am processing mpeg2(TS) data online as output of TBS card DVB Receiver,i have TS buffers and wanna play them buffer by buffer ,all of player components C++ source code that i checked ,have needed a string as a file name (playing a file),my problem is,how can i play processed buffers one by one??? (i am programming in VC++ ,have dedicated one thread for processing and one another for playing processed buffers.)

Comment: Can you show some of the relevant code so we can see the direction you have been trying?

Comment: i have checked the question "process video stream from memory buffer ",but it didn't work out.

Comment: for example i use ffmpeg or solution like using directshow ,they all need a string as a file name for start (the open function) and then do rendering and other stuff for playing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237175/process-video-stream-from-memory-buffer/10918972#10918972

Comment: would  you please guide me to a solution??

Comment: Question is too broad: what do you mean by playing "buffer by buffer" ? What is a "processed buffer" Can you show the code you have so far ?