# How to decode raw H.264 frames using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, h.264

How to decode **raw H.264 frames** using OpenCV in Python? The script that I use gets H.264 frames over the network as a list of bytes, as described in example below. In the example below, I'll try to explain what bytes (and in which order) come to the python script.

First data (some kind of frame identifier?) that I get is 10 bytes long, and it always looks something like this:

```py
# this 10-byte sequence is always the same when it occurs:
data1 = [ 103, 66, 128, 30, 139, 104, 10, 2, 247, 149 ]
```

After this comes second, *6-byte* long sequence:

```py
# also always the same when it occurs:
data2 = [ 104, 206, 1, 168, 119, 32 ]
```

Finally, after that comes the *key* frame:

```py
# key or I-frame, always starts with this byte sequnce:
key_frame = [ 101, 184, 0, 0, ... ]
```

And key frame is followed by 29 *P-frames*, which always start with this byte sequence:

```py
# predicted or P-frame, always starting with this byte sequence:
p_frame = [ 97, 224, ... ]
```

After that, `data1` comes again, and whole process repeats. Frames that I get from the network can be either *key* frames or *predicted* frames. What I need to do is to somehow load these frame data into OpenCV for further analysis. How can I do that?

Comment: You could use VideoCapture to decode a video from network or device. Not sure the API allows you to pass a data buffer though.

Comment: This answer might help you as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237175/process-video-stream-from-memory-buffer