# Where is opencv2's cvcapture and their subclass?

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, buffer, video-processing

I checked this Topic([process video stream from memory buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237175/process-video-stream-from-memory-buffer)), and I would like to do the same in this 1st answer.
I tried to create a new class file that inherited from cvCapture_FFMPEG, and to override the "open" function.
But I can't find any OpenCV module where there is a class named "cvCapture_FFMPEG".

I’m assuming that "cvCapture_FFMPEG" is nowhere in OpenCV and their API. Am I right? 
If so, could you tell me the best way to handle a buffer in OpenCV?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat), there exists a constructor for `cv::Mat` in which you directly give the buffer representing a frame. Why not try to use this alongside  [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to update the content of the Mat object whenever the buffer has new content?

Something like that:

```
/*myBuffer is a void* pointing on your data.
myBufferType is very important as it will give the number of bytes to 
be read for each element*/
cv::Mat myImage(height, width, myBufferType, myBuffer); 

while(1){

    if(myBufferHasBeenUpdated)
        std::memcpy(Mat.data, myBuffer, numberOfBytesToCopy);

    //Performing some operations on the Mat object
}
```

**EDIT:** I saw you changed the title of your question. Here is the documentation about [cv::VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture#videocapture) that is in the highgui module of OpenCV. If you want to read a video directly from a file, it's the best way to proceed. However, if you want to read a video already in a buffer in memory like the topic you mentioned, I don't think there is a way to easily use it.

Comment: Thanks @Axel B,and sorry for mistitle. I had not checked "memcpy" yet. I'll give it a try