# OpenCV load video from url

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video

I have a video file (i.e. `https://www.example.com/myvideo.mp4`) and need to load it with OpenCV.

Doing the equivalent with an image is fairly trivial:

```
imgReq = requests.get("https://www.example.com/myimage.jpg")
imageBytes = np.asarray(bytearray(data), dtype=np.uint8)
loadedImage = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

I would like to do something similar to the following (where `loadedVideo` will be similar to what OpenCV returns from `cv2.VideoCapture`):

```
videoReq = requests.get("https://www.example.com/myimage.mp4")
videoBytes = np.asarray(bytearray(data), dtype=np.uint8)
loadedVideo = cv2.videodecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

But `cv2.videodecode` does not exist. Any ideas?

---

**Edit:** Seeing as this may be a dead end with only OpenCV, I'm open for solutions that combine other imaging libraries before loading into OpenCV...if such a solution exists.

Comment: if you download the video to your hard disk and try VideoCapture there, does it work?

Comment: Yes it would, but I can't imagine that's the most efficient method as it introduces disk IO into the problem rather than keeping everything in memory. I'm looking for the lowest latency possible here.

Comment: no, it was just a test to reduce error sources (like mossing codecs)

Comment: Do you want to hold the entire video in memory or do you want it to act as a streaming video?

Comment: I'd like to hold the entire video in memory.

Comment: OpenCV currently does not support decoding video from memory. If you can tinker with source code, then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10918972/2286337).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that `cv2.videocode` is not a valid `OpenCV API` either in `OpenCV 2.x` or `OpenCV 3.x`.

Below is a sample code it works in `OpenCV 3` which uses `cv2.VideoCapture` class.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Open a sample video available in sample-videos
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture('https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4')
#if not vcap.isOpened():
#    print "File Cannot be Opened"

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    #print cap.isOpened(), ret
    if frame is not None:
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        # Press q to close the video windows before it ends if you want
        if cv2.waitKey(22) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        print "Frame is None"
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
vcap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print "Video stop"
```

You may check this [Getting Started with Videos](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) tutorial for more information.

Hope this help.

Comment: It's not working in ubuntu 16.04. How can I stream directly on OpenCV?
I have installed OpenCV using the pip install opencv-python==3.4.5 or also tried to version 4.

Comment: @Akash Did you check the url? The one mentioned above in the answer is broken.

Comment: @abggcv, I have found the solution. The HTTPS URL is not working directly in Ubuntu due to SSL issue. Might work when building OpenCV with OpenSSL FLAG. In my case, I have changed the URL HTTPS to HTTP it's working perfectly.

Comment: I know that this is out of the scope of the original question but would You know how to read the audio stream at the same time if one is available?

Comment: @Kaszanas you should open a new question and provide more information of your use case for getting answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to read the video using VideoCapture. there is no other way around that for now. unless you define it yourself.

remember a video is a combination of images changing at defined frame rate.

So You can read each frame in a while loop. as you apply the imdecode function.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('https://www.example.com/myimage.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, image = cap.read()    
    loadedImage = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imshow('frame',loadedImage)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```