# Unable to display video from Youtube with Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pafy

I am trying to get video from Youtube using Python 3.5, OpenCV 3.4.3 and Pafy 0.5.4. The problem is that `cv2.VideoCapture(video_from_url)` does not see the video from url. I also have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185654/opencv-load-video-from-url) topic previously. Here is the code that works well if `video_from_url` variable is replaced with a path to video on my local PC.

```
import pafy
import cv2

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCSd0slqzcQ&start_radio=1&list=RDiCSd0slqzcQ'

video_pafy = pafy.new(url)

video_from_url = video_pafy.getbest().url

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_from_url)

while True:

  ret, frame = cap.read()
  print(ret) # False

  """
  Further video processing
  """
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to work directly off that URL; the URL playback capability of OpenCV is quite limited, and that's also a very shaky way to get video and not guaranteed at all to continue to work. The best bet is to use that tool to download videos, and then play off the downloaded videos...

Comment: It works for me correctly.

Comment: @eyllanesc Which python and opencv versions are you using?

Comment: @YuriiM. opencv 3.4.3 pỳthon 3.7

Comment: @eyllanesc I've tried to run with python 3.7 and still unsuccessful. Did you build opencv from source or installed previously built binaries?