# I want to read a video in opencv using url

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I used host='0.0.0.0' so that i can run this code from a different machine. Now suppose my ip is ###.###.#.###.
What i want to do is pass a link like this: ###.###.#.###/ and the video will run on the browser.
I tried this way but it seems like it is wrong approach.

For a rough work, i simply tried to run this using opencv only
I pasted the link like this:
video_link = <'link.com'>
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_link)
It worked.

This is what i tried

```
from flask import Flask
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/video/<string:url>")
def input_value(url):
    link = str(url)
    return link

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(link)

    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('output', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I'm getting messages like `404`

Comment: Please see below url which shows how to use URL directly from Open VideoCapture method 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185654/opencv-load-video-from-url

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for. I already mentioned that i tried this.

Comment: No, you didn't mention that you tried this link anywhere

Comment: This is an example:
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/add/<int:number>,<int:number2>") 
def add(number, number2):
    x = number
    y = number2
    result = x + y
    return str(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)

When i type this on the address bar:
###.###.#.###:5000/add/3,5
It gives me a blank white page with 8 as the result printed on the top left corner.

Comment: I mentioned this:
For a rough work, i simply tried to run this using opencv only I pasted the link like this:
 video_link = <'link.com'> 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_link) 
It worked.
I tried this on vs code

Answer (score 0):

i see that you have not provided the url to fetch the video which is giving 404 error message.

```
@app.route("/video/<string:url>")
```

line 2, repace  with the desired url which includes video you want to show.

**such as :**

```
@app.route("/video/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jvf5y21ZqtQ")
```

Comment: I didn't provide the url because i will pass the url as a parameter from my web browser..like this....123.147.1.355:5000/video/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jvf5y21ZqtQ
and it should display the video on the web browser

Comment: For this you should use call by reference method.
for example

def url(x):
    print "x=",x," id=",id(x)
    x=123.147.1.355:5000
    print "x=",x," id=",id(x)
After that use this url(x) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
from flask import Flask
import cv2
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/video/<path:url>")
def input_value(url):
    counter = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)


    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret:
            counter += 1
            cv2.imshow('output', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break
    return str(counter)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

This code takes the link from the address bar, then runs the video on my machine and returns the counter value on the webpage

Comment: why did you immediately answer the question when you asked it recently?

Comment: I didn't answer it immediately. I was looking for answers and also figuring out the code at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code, I believe you want video to be visible on a webpage. For that just use a html video tag and pass in the URL from the django as value in the webpage.