# how to process with opencv and python a live video transmission from a webrtc site

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to process with OpenCV and python a live video transmission from a WebRTC site. But I can't open the video with

```
cv2.videocapture (URL)
```

When I try to open the video whith `cv2.videocapture`, it returns this error: [

> ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (116) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:235: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: error, expected '0?[1-9][du]'

How could I open the video that is compatible with OpenCV?
I appreciate it if you demonstrate the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV load video from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185654/opencv-load-video-from-url)

Comment: which link are you trying to open?

Comment: The link is a webRTC page that contains images from an Ip camera

Comment: can you post the link

Comment: This is the link: https://webrtc-streamer.herokuapp.com/webrtcstreamer.html?video=Bahia&options=rtptransport%3Dtcp%26timeout%3D60&

Comment: I guess OpenCV has not built in support for reading webrtc stream. you must use some external libraries.