# Correct way for working with raw data when encoding using FFmpeg

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-library

I am working on the android library for encoding/decoding raw data through ffmpeg. Every example I found uses files, it either reads or writes to a file. However, I am using raw byte array representing RGBA  image for encoder input and byte array for encoder output. Lets focus on encoding part for this question.

My function looks like this:

```
int encodeRGBA(uint8_t *image, int imageSize, int presentationTimestamp,
 uint8_t *result, int resultSize)
```

Where `image` is byte array containing raw rgba image data, `imageSize` is length of that array, `presentationTimestamp` is just counter used by `AVFrame` for setting `pts`, `result` is preallocated byte array with some defined length (currently with size matching width x height) and `resultSize` is byte array length (width x height). Returned int value represents actually used length of preallocated array. I am aware that this is not the best approach for sending data back to java and this is also part of the question. Is there a better way for returning result?

Example found [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/encode_video.c) for encoding, directly writes byte data to the frame->data[0] (different approach for different formats, RGBA or YUV). But google search for "ffmpeg read from memory" results in examples like [this](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/avio_reading.c), [this](https://riptutorial.com/ffmpeg/example/30955/reading-from-memory) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237175/process-video-stream-from-memory-buffer). All of them suggesting using `AVIOContext`.

I am confused how to use AVFormatContext with AVCodecContext for encoding?

Currently I have encoder working using first approach and I am successfully returning results as described (with preallocated byte array). I would like to know if that is wrong approach? Should I be using `AVIOContext` for handling byte arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be using AVIOContext for handling byte arrays?

No. AVIOContext if for working with files and or containers in memory. In that case avformat is required to read encoded frames out of A byte array. You are working with raw frames directly and don’t require using avformat.

Comment: thanks! so it is ok to directly write rawdata into avframe->data and do the encoding with it?

Comment: Honest question, was my answer not clear? I believe I answered that in context.