# Read video from base64 in python

Tags: python, video, base64, plotly-dash

I would like to process a video that I receive through an upload component in plotly dash. Currently I am creating a tempfile and then reading the video with opencv. However, I would like to avoid writing the file to disk. Is there a way to process the video directly from memory? My code looks like this:

```
def process_motion(contents, filename):
    print("Processing video: " + filename)
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
        temp.write(decoded)

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(temp.name)

        frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
        fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        
        # some calculations
```

Comment: You're looking for `io.BytesIO`

Comment: @PaulM. Could you give me a hint how to iterate over the individual frames and maybe read the fps with `io.BytesIO`?

Comment: Not with `cv2.VideoCapture`. (Well, at least not in any simple and sane way that I'm aware of.)  Look for some library (maybe a Python wrapper around ffmpeg?) that's actually focused on decoding video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question

as @[Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) has correctly mentioned, the correct keyword to search would be **video decoding**. The thing is, like OpenCV, must of decoding libraries in python using FFMPEG as the backend and most of them are wrappers around the FFMPEG executable (run FFMPEG in subprocess), and since FFMPEG accepts file path for decoding (or URL for decoding video stream) those wrappers also accept file path.

AFAIK, the only wrapper library which accepts bytes as input to decode video and get all frames is [imageio](https://github.com/imageio/imageio) which behind the scene also converts bytes to a temp file and decode it using FFMPEG.

Here is the comparison of using imageio and your solution.

```
import base64
import imageio.v3 as iio
import cv2
from time import perf_counter
import tempfile
import numpy as np

with open("example.mp4", "rb") as videoFile:
    base_text = base64.b64encode(videoFile.read())


buffer = base64.b64decode(base_text)

start = perf_counter()
frames = iio.imread(buffer, index=None, format_hint=".mp4")
print("iio ffmpeg pluing: ", perf_counter() - start)
print(frames.shape)


start = perf_counter()
frames = iio.imread(buffer, index=None, plugin="pyav", format_hint=".mp4")
print("iio pyav pluing: ", perf_counter() - start)
print(frames.shape)

start = perf_counter()
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    temp.write(buffer)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(temp.name)

    frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    success, frame = cap.read()
    frames = [frame]
    while success:
        success, frame = cap.read()
        frames.append(frame)
    frames = np.stack(frames[:-1])
print("cv2: ", perf_counter() - start)
print(frames.shape)
============================================
iio ffmpeg pluing:  0.3905044999992242
(901, 270, 480, 3)
No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
iio pyav pluing:  0.3710011249931995
(901, 270, 480, 3)
cv2:  0.2388888749992475
(901, 270, 480, 3)
```

Note: if you are able to create a python wrapper for FFMPEG it is possible to convert a bytes array to a format that is acceptable FFMPEG's stream decoding function. as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10918972/4527628)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using imageio works perfectly, however I have to pass `io.BytesIO(buffer)` to `iio.imread`. The only thing I still have problems with is reading the metadata with `iio.immeta(io.BytesIO(buffer), plugin='pyav')`. Does this by any chance work for you? I always receive the error: OSError: 'pyav' can not handle the given uri.

Comment: Why don't you pass buffer directly? why `BytesIO` ? based on the documentation the uri (first argument of `iio.immeta`) should be `uri : {str, pathlib.Path, bytes, file}`

Comment: I got a little confused as `iio.imread` requires `io.BytesIO` in version 2.23.0 although the documentation states otherwise. Passing buffer works :)

Comment: using ffmpeg from OpenCV **does not involve a subprocess**. it involves shared objects (libraries). PyAV also does not use a subprocess. it properly calls library functions of the ffmpeg libraries.